# Algorithm attack on an hash attack (Python)

Tags: hash, attack

Here is an attempt at a Python implementation of what is described in the paper I attached as an image.

The algorithm is too slow or there is something wrong with the code. Any ideas!

```
import random

def left_rotate(x: int, n: int) -> int:
    """
    Circularly shift an integer 'x' left by 'n' positions.
    :return: A 32-bit integer value
    """
    return ((x << n) | (x >> (32 - n))) & 0xFFFFFFFF

def f(x: int, y: int, z: int) -> int:
    return (x & y) | (~x & z)

def g(x: int, y: int, z: int) -> int:
    return (x & y) | (x & z) | (y & z)

def h(x: int, y: int, z: int) -> int:
    return x ^ y ^ z

def random_32_bit_num() -> int:
    """
    Return a random 32-bit integer number.
    """
    return random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFFFF)

def flip_random_bit(number: int) -> int:
    """
    Return the number that results from randomly changing the value of one bit in a given 32-bit integer 'number'.
    """
    # Ensure that number is a 32-bit integer
    number &= 0xFFFFFFFF

    bit_to_flip = random.randint(0, 31)

    return number ^ (1 << bit_to_flip)

def condition_5_35(q: list) -> bool:
    """
    Condition (5.35), page 220.

    G(Q15, Q14, Q13) - G(Q'15, Q'14, Q'13) = 1.

    Covers Step 4 of the attack.
    """

    a = g(q[15][0], q[14][0], q[13][0])
    b = g(q[15][1], q[14][1], q[13][1])

    return (a - b) & 0xFFFFFFFF == 1

def extract_bits(y: int, i: int, j: int) -> int:
    """
    Return the integer that results from extracting bits i through j of the input 'Y'.
    """

    # Calculate the number of bits to shift
    shift_amount = j - (i - 1)

    # Shift Y to the right to align the desired bits to the least significant positions
    aligned_bits = y >> i

    # Create a bitmask to keep only the desired bits
    bitmask = (1 << shift_amount) - 1

    # Perform bitwise AND to extract the desired bits
    return aligned_bits & bitmask

def condition_5_38(q: list, j: int):

    F = f(q[14][0], q[13][0], -1)
    F_tilde = f(q[14][1], q[13][1], 0)

    expression = F_tilde - F - left_rotate(q[15][1], 13) + left_rotate(q[15][0], 13)
    expression &= 0xFFFFFFFF

    return extract_bits(expression, j, 31) == 0

def smallest_index_5_38(q: list) -> int:
    """
    The smallest index for which condition (5.38) holds
    """

    # If the rightmost bit is non-zero then set j = 32.
    j = 32

    i = 31
    while condition_5_38(q, i) and i >= 0:

        j = i
        i -= 1

    return j

def initialize_q_values() -> list:
    """
    Create a tuple of lists representing (Q, Q') coordinate-like in the context of MD4.

    Covers Step 1 of the attack.
    """

    q = list([[0, 0] for _ in range(48)])

    q[11][0] = 0

    q[12][0] = -1
    q[12][1] = 0

    return q

def initialize_basic_variables(q: list) -> list:
    """
    Randomly select the "basic" variables.

    Covers Step 2 of the attack.
    """

    q[14][0] = random_32_bit_num()
    q[15][0] = random_32_bit_num()
    q[16][0] = random_32_bit_num()
    q[17][0] = random_32_bit_num()
    q[18][0] = random_32_bit_num()
    q[19][0] = random_32_bit_num()

    return q

def transform_solution(q: list) -> list:

    q[14][0] = flip_random_bit(q[14][0])
    q[15][0] = flip_random_bit(q[15][0])
    q[16][0] = flip_random_bit(q[16][0])
    q[17][0] = flip_random_bit(q[17][0])
    q[18][0] = flip_random_bit(q[18][0])
    q[19][0] = flip_random_bit(q[19][0])

    return q

def system_equations(q: list) -> list:
    """

    Satisfy the specified equations (5.28) through (5.32), page 219.

    Covers Step 3 of the attack.
    """

    q[15][1] = (q[15][0] - g(q[18][1], q[17][0], q[16][0]) + g(q[18][0], q[17][0], q[16][0])
                + left_rotate(q[19][1], 19) - left_rotate(q[19][0], 19) - 1)

    q[14][1] = (q[14][0] - g(q[17][0], q[16][0], q[15][1]) + g(q[17][0], q[16][0], q[15][0])
                + left_rotate(q[18][1], 23) - left_rotate(q[18][0], 23))

    q[13][0] = (left_rotate(q[14][0], 21) - left_rotate(q[14][1], 21))

    q[13][1] = q[13][0] - g(q[16][0], q[15][1], q[14][1]) + g(q[16][0], q[15][0], q[14][0])

    q[10][0] = (left_rotate(q[13][1], 25) - left_rotate(q[13][0], 25))

    q[15][1] &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    q[14][1] &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    q[13][0] &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    q[13][1] &= 0xFFFFFFFF
    q[10][0] &= 0xFFFFFFFF

    return q

def main():
    """

    Satisfy all conditions to initiate the attack.

    Covers Step 1 to Step 4 of the attack.
    """
    print("Step 1")
    # Step 1
    x = initialize_q_values()

    print("Step 2")
    # Step 2
    y = initialize_basic_variables(x[:])

    print("Step 3")
    # Step 3
    z = system_equations(y[:])

    print("Step 4")
    # Step 4
    x_temp = x[:]
    while not condition_5_35(z):
        print(condition_5_35(z))
        # Repeat Step 2 and Step 3
        z = system_equations(initialize_basic_variables(x_temp))

    print("Step 5")
    # Step 5
    j = smallest_index_5_38(z)

    print("Into the while!")

    while j != 0:

        a = transform_solution(z[:])
        b = system_equations(a[:])

        if condition_5_35(b):

            j_temp = smallest_index_5_38(b)

            if j_temp < j:

                print("Condition 5.38 satisfied")

                z = b
                j = j_temp
                print(j)

    return z


main()
```

[image: Algorithm]
[image: Condition]

Comment: We should not have to guess if this is [Dobbertin's collision attack on MD4](https://doi.org/10.1007/s001459900047) or something else. Code for such attacks is generally made in a compiled language like C, which is WAY more efficient than Python for that kind of things (and more readable too, since arithmetic on uint32_t matches that in MD4, making masking with 0xffffffff implicit). However, it took seconds on a PC in 1998, so it's feasible in python nowadays. Does the algorithm work, albeit slowly?

Comment: The proper answer would be that it is not working. Although when it runs it prints some decreasing j values, this is done during hours of running. In the end, it does not produce a j value of zero in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: So most likely something is wrong in the code (or the publication). Even though code review is not exactly on-topic, I tried that. But without the publication's (5.28) through (5.32), that's not possible. Can you link to or otherwise designate the publication? First thing I'd do for debugging is add an explicit check that (5.28) through (5.32) are satisfied where they are supposed to be.

Comment: Try to see it updated here including the equations https://paste.pythondiscord.com/TBPQ